# iOS : Google Maps API failing when applying API KEY restrictions

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, api-key

When I use Google API key without any API key restrictions, Google Maps loads just fine in the app. As soon as I apply restrictions such as:

- Application Restriction : iOS app : Accept requests from an iOS
  application with one of these bundle identifiers
- API Restrictions by service

The app rashes medially on maps access.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you check enabling billing and what is your bundle identifier to call google maps API? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key

Comment: @tamsler Can u share piece of source that is creating crash? I guess i can help you.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Only system libraries are referenced in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an [working example](https://github.com/muhammadwaqas91/GoogleMapsTest) with [snapshots](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gv283cgfwiq49i6/GoogleMaps%20Restrictions%20.zip?dl=0). I just followed the the [Google Maps tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start). It did not crashed for me with or without restrictions for ios app.

google maps working example added

Location Manager added

Location Updates handled

Network Reachability Added

Hope it helps.

Comment: @tamsler check out the Answer

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT (Signal abort) means there should be something to signal but it's aborted some how. Usually it tells you why its crashing.

- So first Check the console for description:

[[image: Console[1]]

- If there is nothing printed, Try simulator instead of real device.
  Its much more powerful than real device for debugging purposes.
- Make sure you are in the debugging configuration:

[[image: Edit scheme[2]]
 - You can turn on memory management options in diagnostics for better results if you doesn't find the issue: (Specially **Zombie Objects**)

[[image: diagnostics[3]]

- Also you can try add some exception breakpoint to catch the issue before it going happen:

[[image: exception breakpoint[4]]

I think one of the above should lead you to something more specific about the issue and it's reason. Then you can absolutely handle it.